# Why is this manhattan heuristic inadmissble?

Tags: algorithm, a-star, heuristics

In [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm) article, which explains the A* algorithm, it says that for that for the given problem (finding shortest distance between two points where there is a wall as an obstacle), the Manhattan distance is not admissible. See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20171019182159/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/heuristics.htm)
Why is that? Does it overestimate the distance in any case? If yes, when?

Comment: Yes it overestimates in certain cases. I'm thinking it's probably the `10` coefficient that's to blame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a chunk from aStarLibrary.bb (following links from your link)

;Figure out its G cost
        If Abs(a-parentXval) = 1 And Abs(b-parentYVal) = 1 Then
            addedGCost = 14 ;cost of going to diagonal squares
        Else
            addedGCost = 10 ;cost of going to non-diagonal squares
        End If
        Gcost(a,b) = Gcost(parentXval,parentYVal)+addedGCost

```
    ;Figure out its H and F costs and parent
    Hcost(openList(m)) = 10*(Abs(a - targetx) + Abs(b - targety)) ; record the H cost of the new square
```

The heuristic (Hcost) for a move from (0, 0) to (1,1) will be 10 * (1 + 1) = 20. The GCost (cost of a move) treats this a single diagonal move of cost 14. So yes, it is an over-estimate.